# Named Distribution to represent this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

A jar contains 7 white marbles, 5 black marbles, and 3 red marbles. We draw marbles from the jar, with replacement, until we have drawn two white marbles, and let X count the number of black marbles drawn. At first I thought this random variable X would follow a negative binomial distribution, however I realized that picking a white does not guarantee us to get a black. So is there any named distribution that can represent this random variable?